# How to send base64 image from angularjs to laravel using POST method?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Hi I am new to laravel and angularjs. My doubt is how to send uploaded image(convert base64) to laravel

My html code look like below

```
<input type="file" class="upload upload-button" fileinput="fileinput"
       filepreview="image" file-model = "myFile">
```

Give some Idea because i want store blob(image) in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->input('profile_pic')); $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);


 Storage::put('user_profile/croped/' . myimage.jpg, (string) $image_base64, 'public');
```